# Is a mass-spring system necessarily calculated via a matrix multiplication on all points, or is it possible to calculate it point-wise?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Is a mass-spring system necessarily calculated via a matrix multiplication on all points, or is it possible to calculate it point-wise?

I've seen two versions:

$x(t + ∆t) = x(t) + ∆tv(t + ∆t)$

which looks like a calculation on individual points, in:

> Nealen, Andrew, et al. "Physically based deformable models in computer
> graphics." EUROGRAPHICS 2005 STAR–STATE OF THE ART REPORT. 2005.
> https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/egstar2005.pdf

and a clear matrix-form in:

> Liu, Tiantian, et al. "Fast simulation of mass-spring systems." ACM
> Transactions on Graphics (TOG) 32.6 (2013): 1-7.
> https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eladislav/liu13fast/liu13fast.pdf

Comment: The position updates are usually the trivial operations. The interaction between position occurs in the force calculation that go into the velocity updates.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So this would suggest that they can be calculated point-wise, independently.

Comment: Yes, the part that you wrote down. In the not displayed part, the forces from the spring effect a force difference between the ends of the spring, but no separate force individually. It results a sparse but non-trivial system of equations for the accelerations. This needs to be solved, quickly and repeatedly, re-using results as much as possible, inside the implicit Euler steps and also between the Euler steps.